# Is this proof that $u^+\in W^{1,p}(U)$ correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces

Evans - Edition 1 - Chapter 5 - Problem 17 - p292

I want to show that $u^+$ is in $W^{1,p}(U)$.

> Outline. 1) I define $u^+$ as the limit of some collection of functions. 2) I show that it's derivative is bounded. 3) I make use of three facts, that composition of $L^p$ functions is $L^p$, that the product of two $L^p$ functions is $L^p$ and that $u_{x_i}$ is $L^p$.

So we have $u^+=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} F_\epsilon(u)$ for:
$$F_\epsilon(z)=\begin{cases}(z^2+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}-\epsilon&z\geq 0\\0&z<0\end{cases},\qquad F'_\epsilon(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+\epsilon^2}}&z\geq 0\\0&z<0\end{cases}$$
and we see that $F_\epsilon'\leq 1$, so it is bounded. We see that $F_\epsilon(0)=0$ and so composition of this with any $L^P(U)$ function will be in $L^P(U)$.

So now since we have $u^+=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (F_\epsilon \circ u)$, we consider $\phi\in C^\infty_c(U)$:
$$\int_U u^+ \phi_{x_i}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_U (F'_\epsilon\circ u)u_{x_i}\phi dx$$
So the weak derivative is $(F_\epsilon'\circ u)u_{x_i}$. Since $L^p$ space is an algebra, and $u\in W^{1,p}(U)\implies u_{x_i}\in L^p(U)$, then we need only check that $(F'_\epsilon\circ u)$ is in $L^p(U)$, but also, since composition of $L^p(U)$ functions is in $L^p(U)$, we need only check that $F'_\epsilon\in L^p(U)$ right?

So then since we know this is bounded, we just take:
$$\left(\int_U |(F_\epsilon')|^p dx\right)^{1/p}\leq \int_U |1|dx<\infty$$
so $F'_\epsilon\in L^p(U)$ and we are done?

Comment: Composition of $L^2$ is not $L^2$, consider $f(x) := min(1,1/|x|) ∈ L^2(\mathbb R),\ f(f(x)) = 1 \notin L^2$. 

Product of two $L^p$ functions is not $L^p$, only $L^{p/2}$ by Holder. Same $f$ above provides counterexample.

Comment: On bounded domains say $[-1,1]$ an easier counterexample for the first property is composing $1/|x|∈ L^2$  with $\sqrt{|x|}∈ L^2$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the product property requires a different counterexample, please use $f=g=1/|x|$ on $[-1,1]$, $fg \notin L^2([-1,1])$.

Comment: Oh, only $L^\infty$ is an algebra

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to pass to the limit. You have $0\le F_\varepsilon(z)\le \sqrt{z^2+1}\le |z|+1$ and so 
$|F_\varepsilon(u)\phi_{x_i}|\le\Vert \phi_{x_i}\Vert_\infty (|u|+1)$. Assuming that $U$ is bounded, the right-hand side is integrable, and so by LDCT
$$\int_U F_\varepsilon(u)\phi_{x_i}\,dx\to \int_U u^+\phi_{x_i}\,dx.$$
Similarly, you have to apply LDCT for $F'_\varepsilon(u) u_{x_i}$. You have
$|F'_\varepsilon(u) u_{x_i}\phi_{x_i}|\le 1\Vert \phi_{x_i}\Vert_\infty|u_{x_i}|$, since $0\le F'_\varepsilon(z) \le 1$, and so by LDCT
$$\int_U F'_\varepsilon(u) u_{x_i}\phi\,dx\to \int_{\{u>0\}} u_{x_i}\phi\,dx.$$
You also need to prove that $F_\varepsilon(u)\in W^{1,p}(U)$. You need to use density of smooth functions. If $u$ is smooth, since $F_\varepsilon$ is $C^\infty$, the composition is smooth. For the general case you need to use density of smooth functions in $W^{1,p}$.